# Spark SQL build for hive?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have downloaded spark release - 1.3.1 and package type is Pre-build for Hadoop 2.6 and later

now i want to run below scala code using spark shell so i followed this steps

```
1. bin/spark-shell

2. val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

3. sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (key INT, value STRING)")
```

Now the problem is if i verity it on hue browser like

```
select * from src;
```

then i get

> table not found exception

that means table not created how do i configure hive with spark shell to make this successful. i want to use SparkSQL also i need to read and write data from hive.

i randomly heard that we need to copy hive-site.xml file somewhere in spark directory

can someone please explain me with the steps - SparkSQL and Hive configuration

Thanks
Tushar

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the hive-site.xml direction is correct. Take a look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables .

Also it sounds like you wish to create a hive table from spark, for that look at "Saving to Persistent Tables" in the same document as above.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd point copied from same documentation link. . .need more detail thx